# How can I merge a list with a nested list?

Tags: python

I have two lists. The first one is a simple list with one entry:

```
l = [hello]
```

The second one is a nested list, with several thousand entries

```
i = [[world, hi], 
     [world, hi], 
     [world, hi], 
     [world, hi]]
```

Now I want to insert the entry from list `l` into the nested lists of `i` like this:

```
i = [[hello, world, hi], 
     [hello, world, hi], 
     [hello, world, hi], 
     [hello, world, hi]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does your data actually look like? Switching to a different data structure may be the right thing to do. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve that

```
i = [l+x for x in i]
```

Comment: Clearly the most Pythonic

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `insert` method on each sublist in `i`.

```
for sublist in i:
    sublist.insert(0, l[0])
```

If you don't want to modify `i` in place, and would prefer to build a new list, then

```
i = [[l[0], *sublist] for sublist in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

simple: `[[*l,*el] for el in i]`

Output:

```py
[['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', ' hi']]
```

I guess the benefits is that no matter how many elements you have in `l`, they will all be put in front of the stuff in `i`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the element to the list you want

```
l = ["hello"]
i = [["world", "hi"], 
     ["world", "hi"], 
     ["world", "hi"], 
     ["world", "hi"]]

x = []
for y in i:
    x.append(l+y)

x
```

output:

```
[['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', 'hi'],
 ['hello', 'world', 'hi']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should do the trick:

```
l = ['hello']
i = [['world', 'hi'], 
     ['world', 'hi'], 
     ['world', 'hi'], 
     ['world', 'hi']]

for j in i:
    for k in l:
        j = j.append(k)
```

I'm just iterating through your list `i`, nesting another for loop to iterate through the *simpler* list `l` (to account for the case whereby it has multiple elements), and simply appending each entry in `l` to the current list in `i`.